# Remove all occurrence of new line between two patterns (sed or awk?)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a simple problem. I need to remove \n all occurrence of them between two patterns. ie.

```
<INFOSTART
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
<INFOEND
<INFOSTART
G=1
Z=3
<INFOEND
```

So I would like to the output be something like following

```
A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4
G=1 Z=3
```

any idea how I can do it? And thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple state machine with `awk`, such as with the following input file, slightly modified to also allow text *outside* the markers (if there is no such text, it will still work as desired, this is just to handle *extra* cases):

```
xyzzy
plugh
<INFOSTART
A=1
B=2
C=3
D=4
<INFOEND
twisty
passages
<INFOSTART
G=1
Z=3
<INFOEND
after
last
```

With a data file like that (or your original), the following `awk` command gives you what you need, combining lines between the start and end markers into a single line:

```
awk ' /^<INFOSTART$/ {inside=1; sep=""; next}
      /^<INFOEND$/   {inside=0; print ""; next}
      inside         {printf sep""$0; sep=" "; next}
                     {print}' input_file

xyzzy
plugh
A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4
twisty
passages
G=1 Z=3
after
last
```

Examining the `awk` code in more detail, the following sections expand on each line.

---

The following segment runs whenever you find a line consisting of only the start marker. It sets the `inside` state to true (non-zero) to indicate that you should start combining lines, and sets the initial separator to the empty string to ensure no leading space on the combined line. The `next` simply goes and grabs the next input line immediately, starting a new cycle:

```
/^<INFOSTART$/ {inside=1; sep=""; next}
```

---

Assuming you didn't find a start marker, this segment runs for an end marker. If found, the `inside` state is set back to false (zero) to start printing out lines exactly as they appear in the input file. It also outputs a newline to properly finish the combined line, then restarts the cycle with the next input line:

```
/^<INFOEND$/   {inside=0; print ""; next}
```

---

If you've established that the line is neither a start nor end marker, your behaviour depends on the `inside` state. For true, you need to combine the input lines into a single output line, so you simply print, without a trailing newline, the separator followed by the line itself. Then you set the separator to a space so the next input line will be properly separated from the previous one. It then cycles back for the next input line:

```
inside         {printf sep""$0; sep=" "; next}
```

---

Finally, if you get here, you know you're outside of a start/end section so you just echo the line exactly as it exists in the input file:

```
               {print}'
```

---

If you don't want the nicely formatted version, you can use the following minified version, assuming you're certain the only `<INFO...` lines are the start and end markers:

```
awk '/^<INFOS/{a=1;b="";next}/^<INFOE/{a=0;print"";next}a{printf b$0;b=" ";next}1'
```

However, since this will probably be in a script rather than a one-liner command, I'd tend to stick with the readable version myself.

Answer (score 4):

With `tr` and `sed`:

```
AMD$ tr '\n' ' ' < File | sed 's/<INFOSTART //g; s/<INFOEND /\n/g'
A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4
G=1 Z=3
```

Replace all `newlines` with `space` first. Then use `sed` to remove all `<INFOSTART` and replace all `<INFOEND` with `newlines`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
< input perl -ne 's/\n/ /, print if $s = /<INFOSTART/ .. ($e = /<INFOEND/)
                                    and $s > 1 and !$e;
                  print "\n" if $e'
```

$s is true when we're between the tags (using the `..` operator). $e is true if we're matching the end tag, $s is 1 when we're matching the start tag.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^<INFOSTART/d;:a;N;/^<INFOEND/M!s/\n/ /;ta;P;d' file
```

This deletes lines beginning `<INFOSTART` or `<INFOEND` and replaces the newlines between all other lines by spaces.

The solution can be pared down further (providing the file is well formed) to:

```
sed '/^</d;:a;N;/^</M!s/\n/ /;ta;P;d' file
```